# ¿Cómo establecer una condición en iloc?

Tags: python, pandas

Cómo es posible establecer una condición al utilizar iloc? Mi data es:

```
indice     var1  var2
2019-01-01  01   08
2019-01-02  05   08
2019-01-03  04   08
...
2019-02-01  08   09
2019-02-02  07   08
...
```

Necesito crear un df idéntico, pero solo con las filas corrrespondientes al primero de cada mes.
He intentado algo como esto, pero sin éxito:

```
df_cut = data.iloc[data.index[1,1]==01,:]
```

¿Alguna idea? El problema radica en la condición. señalarle básicamente que los elementos 8 y 9 del indice deben ser "01".
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Igual te sirve este post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50292460/10540710

Comment: SI, lo vi, pero allí la condición es sobre posición del indice. En mi caso la condición debe ser una posición sobre una posición.

Comment: De todas formas llegúué al resultado que quería utilizando:
```
data['day'] = data.index.map(lambda x: x.day)
df_cut = data.loc[data['day']==1]
```
Pero si a alguien se ocurre la forma original por la que pregunté, se agradece  enormemente vuestro aporte :)

Comment: te sirve asi `df['indice'].apply(lambda x: '0'+str(pd.to_datetime(x).date().day) if pd.to_datetime(x).date().day < 10 else str(pd.to_datetime(x).date().day))` ?